# RIA Service ObjectContext filter included records

Tags: silverlight, wcf, ria, domainservices

Using RIA Domain services with entity framework 4, I am having trouble to get the entity with filtered related items.

For Example,
Given: Order table and Product table (1 order has many products)

I have service returns Order with Products loaded, e.g.

```
    public IQueryable<Order> GetOrderById(int orderId)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Order
                                 .Include("Products")
                                 .Where(n=>n.OrderId == orderId);
    }
```

Question,

Is there a way to filter the Products record in the linq query in this case? 
Say, return the order of the specified Id and **include the Products which prices are higher than 100.0**; return **Empty/Null** Products if there isn't any. The point here is to **return the Order even though there isn't any products meet the criteria**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
var query = from o in ObjectContext.Order.Include("Products")
            join p in ObjectContext.Product on o.ProductId equals p.ProductId
            where o.OrderId == orderId and p.Price > 100
            select o;
```

Comment: Thanks Rus for your answer, before I mark the final answer I'd like to see more alternatives.

Comment: Ok thanks Rus for the answer, I was waiting for other alternatives but your one should be good enough.